# Ansible: is it possible to resize ext4 filesystem?

Tags: linux, ansible

How I can resize `ext4` filesystem via Ansible? I know about the [filesystem](http://docs.ansible.com/filesystem_module.html) module, but I didn't see a "resize" parameter, or something else about it ...

Comment: i want to extend filesystem.

Comment: how have you tried to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the source of the [filesystem module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/73bdc396a359b8aa2c912eb98ccde1b02f35fcb1/system/filesystem.py) as it currently stands, you can see that there doesn't seem to be anything you could use to resize a filesystem.

Thankfully, you have options: the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) and the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html).

The command module is preferred over the shell module because it's not affected by the user environment, so I'll show you how to do it using the approach:

```
- name: "resize my ext4 filesystem, please"
  command: resize2fs /dev/sda1 
  sudo: True
```

where `sda1` is your filesystem.  If you need to enlarge your filesystem first, use the same approach, but make a call to `fdisk` (with the correct command line switches) instead.

Check `man resize2fs` for specific options for that command and the ansible documentation for more information, including parameterizing your command.

Comment: Cheers, if it solves your question, please consider voting up and/or accepting so others know it works.

Comment: Any nice `when` and `changed_when` conditions that make it idempotent?

Comment: @ServerHorror sure, but you'd need some condition -- you could either use a different command to drop a lockfile on disk and only run the resize when the file doesn't exist on a stat or you could say when the `ansible_mount` fact for the relevant device is under some `size_total` integer.

Comment: @tristan: I meant something like ready to "steal" from that :) -- the `command` module seems obvious (to me), more interesting would be the `when` and `changed_when` laid out so that it e.g. doesn't act on xfs filesystems. Then again, it may be better to actually integrate that in the filesystem module of ansible itself :)

Comment: @ServerHorror I can't provide something ready to copy and paste without picking a condition.  If you don't want xfs, `when: not ansible_mounts[0].fstype == 'xfs'`

Comment: @ServerHorror and I'm not sure that i agree that it should be in the filesystem module, but if an issue is raised against the project to add it (and it gets approved), i'm willing to write the code for it

Comment: I expanded this to an idempotent version below.

Comment: you can replace `sudo: true` with `become: true` as `sudo` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 12):

In order to make the task [idempotent](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/glossary.html#idempotency), add another task to first check for any unexpanded partitions. E.g., if you want the root partition to be at least 10 GB:

```
  - name: Assert root partition is expanded
    assert: { that: item.mount != '/' or item.size_total > 10737418240 } # 10 GB
    with_items: '{{ ansible_mounts }}'
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: expanded
```

**NOTE:** This task fails if the partition `/` is less than 10 GB.

Next, make the expansion task conditional on `expanded|failed`:

```
  - name: Expand partition
    command: parted /dev/mmcblk0 resizepart 2 15.5GB # NOTE: Assumes 16GB card
    when: expanded|failed
    notify: Expand filesystem
```

In my case, I'm expanding partition 2 on the block device `/dev/mmcblk0` (for the Raspberry Pi). You should of course replace with the device names on your system.

Finally, `notify` triggers filesystem expansion:

```
  handlers:
  - name: Expand filesystem
    command: resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to Ansible; what is the benefit to structuring the `Expand filesystem` step as a handler and notifying it from `Expand partition`, as opposed to just having the `Expand filesystem` as another step directly after `Expand partition` and controlling when it runs via `when: expanded|failed` just like we do for the `Expand partition` step itself?

Comment: for me, the assert function fails with ansible_mounts as I have 5 mounted drives. it finds the correct one but fails for the others. how do I fix that?

Comment: Why use `command: parted` instead of [the parted module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/parted_module.html)?

Answer (score 10):

Don't know if it could help. But, since Ansible `2.0` there is `resizefs` option in the `filesystem` module that is `false` by default and that supports `ext4`.

> If yes, if the block device and filesystem size differ, grow the filesystem into the space.
> Supported for ext2, ext3, ext4, ext4dev, f2fs, lvm, xfs, vfat, swap filesystems.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/filesystem_module.html

```yaml
- name: 'Extend the FS'
  filesystem:
    fstype: 'ext4'
    dev: '/dev/sda1'
    resizefs: yes
```